# Why would a JPG display in Firefox, but not IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, jpeg

This is the weirdest thing I've ever seen. (Dead image removed, was a JPG that was fine everywhere but IE where it didn't display.)

Any ideas? This is driving me insane.

If it helps, this is an image that's been uploaded by a client using a form then moved using PHP and renamed.

Comment: had the same problem just now.

Comment: I had to convert the image from `JPG` to `PNG` to make it work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its because the file is saved as CMYK and not RGB-mode

Comment: Exactly. See here, for example: http://blog.traxor-designs.com/2009/02/internet-explorer-jpeg-cmyk-issues.html

Comment: You, my friend, are a hero among men.

Answer (score 4):

I've been facing a similar problem. In my case image color encoding was the problem.
Check if the image is RGB encoded. CMYK encoding may cause problem in different browsers.